# Can I get Copy and Paste to note transpose, exactly as happens in Cut and Paste?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I copy and paste, then excel moves the cell references down. E.g. References to cell B2 on line 3 become references to line B3 on line 4.

With cut and paste, this doesn't happen, and references to cell B2 remain references to B2.

I want the behavior of the cut and paste, but without losing the original content.

Is there a paste special for that?

Comment: Can you use [absolute references](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/get-to-know-excel-enter-formulas-RZ006107930.aspx?section=13) instead?

Comment: @Excellll I suppose. But what If I wanted to simulate absolute references for just one quick copy and paste, and then leave them as they were?

Comment: Okay, that's why I asked :)

Comment: Doesn't `INDIRECT` do this?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the formula in the formula box and copying-pasting it?  Or do you specifically just want to know if there is a paste-special for this (there isn't)?

Comment: @Madball73 Yeah, that's what I've been doing. I wish there was an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDIRECT()`

So, let's assume the cell A1 has the value "hello"

In B1 I would write `=INDIRECT("A1")`

Now, I can copy B1 to another location and it still references A1.

As you can see, I dragged cell D1 downwards, the same value persists.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, not really what I was looking for, but thanks.